# Where should I ask about how to use web apps?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I figured that SuperUser would be the best place (out of SO, SF, and SU) to ask about webapps, but the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) explicitly states that it is *not about*:

> websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress

So where do I ask about that stuff? I don't mean asking about how to build a website or anything, but how to use a webapp.

Comment: No sites around here for use of web applications, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy

Comment: Ok, close this one as a dupe, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On July 7<sup>th</sup>, you will be able to ask them here:

http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

That would depend on what you mean by "use". If you want to know how to create fanpages on facebook, you'll need to go and find a facebook forum someplace. If you want to incorporate FBML into your application, then you can post those questions on Stack Overflow.